# How to resolve Firestore promise directly to a Vue reactive() proxy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Using Vue 3/Typescript, how do I resolve a FireStore promise resulting in an array of objects, to a reactive proxy object using `map()`?

In this instance, I do not wish to use `forEach()` or Vuex.

```
setup(){
   ...
   const clients = reactive(
       db
           .collection('users')
           .orderBy('name', 'asc')
           .get()
           .then(snapshot =>
               snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                   id: doc.id,
                   name: doc.data().name,
               }))
           )
   )
   ...
}
```

***console.log()***

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
    <state>: "fulfilled"
    <value>: Array [ {…} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init your reactive property by an empty array then mutate inside the `onMounted` hook :

```
setup(){
   ...
   const state = reactive({
     clients:[]
   })

onMounted(()=>{
  db.collection('users')
           .orderBy('name', 'asc')
           .get()
           .then(snapshot =>{
             state.clients=  snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                   id: doc.id,
                   name: doc.data().name,
               }))
           
            })

})
   ...

}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using onMounted() for this situation? I ended up initializing `clients` (as you suggested) as an array of objects, then used `Object.assign()` to override the contents within `then()`. Seems to work.

Comment: Yes you could do that, I used onMounted to just organize the code